# Provider class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created provider class and put it into `app/models/Providers` directory:

```
<?php

//app/models/Providers/NiceUrlServiceProvider.php

namespace Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class NiceUrlServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('niceurl', function()
            {
                return new \Utils\NiceUrl();
            });
    }    
}
```

and facade class in `app/models/Facades` directory:

```
<?php

// app/models/Facades/NiceUrl.php
namespace Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class NiceUrl extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'niceurl'; }

}
```

I have also edited app/config/app.php and added this as provider:

```
'providers' => array(

    // default ones  
    'Providers\NiceUrlServiceProvider',    
),
```

and added alias to Facade:

```
'aliases' => array(

     // default ones
    'NiceUrl'         => 'Facades\NiceUrl',

),
```

When I try to run my app I get:

> Class 'Providers\NiceUrlServiceProvider' not found

```
    *
* @param \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app
* @param string $provider
* @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
*/
public function createProvider(Application $app, $provider)
{
return new $provider($app); // this line marked as causing problem
}
```

However if I comment the line where I add my provider and in `public/index.php` put this code at the end of file:

```
$x = new \Providers\NiceUrlServiceProvider($app);
$x->register();
echo NiceUrl::create('some thing');
```

it works without a problem, so it does not seem to be a problem with autoloading.

Also if I register provider manually using:

```
$app->register('Providers\NiceUrlServiceProvider');

echo NiceUrl::create('some thing');
```

at the end of `public/index.php` it is working without a problem.

Questions:

1. How to make it work?
2. Where should I hold providers/facades files? Here I put them into `model` directory into separate folders.

Comment: What you call `Nice URL` is called URL slug, so you should better keep this terminology

Comment: Also you're putting service namespaces in the model directory. You can do that, but it feels very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple but it was not obvious at all. After adding your provider you need to run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

in your main project directory. It will generate new `autoload_classmap.php` file that will include your service provider. `composer-update` in this case also will work but it's not neccessary and it will take much more time. It's quite strange that it's necessary when you put provider into `app/config/app.php` and it's not necessary when you manually register provider but this is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple but it was not obvious at all. After adding your provider you need to run:

> composer dump-autoload

when you add some folder or other classes which is not in your composer.json autoload you would add it then run the above command.